# Why are some of the weather station coordinates out of the Nigerian boundary?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

The following lines of code have been used to plot points (coordinates)for weather stations in Nigeria, unfortunately, some of the stations fell outside of the country's boundary. I confirm that the latitude and longitude of the weather stations are accurate and double-checked. Any suggestion/solution for this off-shoot would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as feature
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shapereader
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("met_ngstation.csv")

countries = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution='10m',
                                  category='cultural',
                                  name='admin_0_countries')

# Find the Nigeria boundary polygon.
for country in shapereader.Reader(countries).records():
    if country.attributes['SU_A3'] == 'NGA':
        nigeria = country.geometry
        break
else:
    raise ValueError('Unable to find the NGA boundary.')

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax_map = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax_map.set_extent([-1, 19, -1, 17], ccrs.PlateCarree())

#ax_map.coastlines()
ax_map.add_feature(feature.COASTLINE, linewidth=.5)

ax_map.add_geometries([nigeria], ccrs.PlateCarree(), 
edgecolor='0.8',
              facecolor='none')

grid_lines = ax_map.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
grid_lines.top_labels = False
grid_lines.right_labels = False

lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()

ax_map.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax_map.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)

plt.scatter(df['LONG'],df['LAT'],
                color='red', marker='.', 
transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

#plt.savefig('coastlines_ng.pdf')
#plt.savefig('coastlines_ng.png')

plt.show()
```

'''

Link to map:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cNnylUOmi-Dg6ioZE0tQj7xCHRdMPIh8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe the weather stations are offshore?  What is wrong? Where the stations are being placed on the map or where the coastline is being placed?  Are you sure you are reading your lat and lon in properly?

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks for your comment. The weather stations are all land stations. Here is the link to the station coordinates: https://drive.google.com/file/d/152UTebTc_sDbyKDXV3g52jYiVG4n6LEx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The rest of the data is fine,  but...  what is misrepresented in the linked plot?

Comment: At least one data point (Eket) is clearly in the ocean. I've written an answer below about how you can check this kind of thing in future. This does not appear to be a cartopy issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JodyKlymak suggested, this is an issue with the input data, not cartopy.

You can check this by using an online map service like Google Maps

[image: Google map showing one of the scatter points offshore]

From this image, you can see that station "Eket" in the linked dataset, lon=7.95, lat=4.4, is located ~ 10 km offshore of Kwa Ibo. This is typical of meteorological buoys

Always check your input data!

Comment: Alternative explanation: the nearby town of Eket is at 4.65 N, not 4.4, a difference of some 30 km. Maybe the input data are wrong

Comment: Thank you for taking out the time to take a look. While I will not dispute your observations, I will like to point out that, the same coordinates were equally plotted using ArcGIS 10.2 and there were no off-shoot into the ocean. I sincerely wish I could get this sorted out through Cartopy, In addition, I think google Map uses Mercator projection whereas, the codes above use PlateCaree projection.

Comment: The only way the projection matters is if there is a long line being interpolated between two fixed locations.  In this case you are comparing a point to a 10-m resolution coastline so the projection is really not going to matter.    Either the station is really offshore, it’s position is incorrect, or the coastline provided by both cartopy and google maps is wrong by over 10 km.